# Visual editor for graphviz DOT files

Tags: ubuntu, debian, graphviz

Sometimes big .gv/.dot Graphviz DOT files I write get screwed when I use `dot` to export them to .png. Circles get kind of *almost-stacked* and arrows start to get *hard to follow*. I seem to be in the need of a previous stage of *clicking and dragging*, but I don't know which one is the tool.

Which one is the tool?

*I will be wanting to use that tool from Microsoft OS 7, Debian 7 and/or Ubuntu 14. With only one of these (Microsoft v. Debian-like) will be enough.*

Or maybe I just need an improved version of `dot`, maybe getting better representations even at the cost of more iteration. Got ideas?

Comment: Maybe `gephi` is the tool.

Comment: _Gephi currently doesn’t provide a complete support of the DOT format. Subgraphs are not supported, nor custom attributes or size. Only labels and colors are imported if present. Directed and undirected graphs are supported. - [https://gephi.github.io/users/supported-graph-formats/graphviz-dot-format/](https://gephi.github.io/users/supported-graph-formats/graphviz-dot-format/)_